# How to list records by date?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, html

you see I am trying to list the records of a table in my database, but I want to do it in the following way:

1. First, it has to display the date
2. and then all the records on that date should appear

In my table of the database I have 4 fields:

```
id, task, date, time
```

For example there are multiple tasks that are performed in a day, but at different times. Then I have stored in my database many tasks of different days and in different hours. What I want is to list them per day. Consult the database and show a list where the date appears first and then all the tasks that were done on that date, then show the other date and then all the tasks of that date and so on.

Something like that

That's my php code

```
$obj = new Task();
$consult = $obj->Lists();

date_default_timezone_set("America/Mexico_City");
$dateActual = date("Y-m-d");

while ($result = $consult->fetch_object()) {

    echo "<button class='btn btn-default'>date = " . $result->date . "</button><br>";

    $consult2 = $obj->Lists2($dateActual);
    while($result2 = $consult2->fetch_object()) {
          echo "<span>". $result2->time ."</span><br>";
    }
    $dateActual = $result->date;
}
```

my query to the database is:

```
public function Lists2($date) 
{
    global $conexion;

    $sql = "SELECT ar.*, date_format(ar.date, '%d/%m/%Y') as date, 
                   date_format(ar.time, '%r') as time, 
                    u.user as User 
            FROM task_recents ar 
                INNER JOIN user u ON ar.iduser = u.iduser 
            WHERE date = '$date' 
            ORDER BY ar.time DESC";
    $query = $conexion->query($sql);
    return $query;
}

public function Lists() 
{
    global $conexion;

    $sql = "SELECT ar.*, date_format(ar.date, '%d/%m/%Y') as date, 
                    date_format(ar.time, '%r') as time, 
                    u.user as User 
            FROM task_recents ar 
                INNER JOIN user u ON ar.iduser = u.iduser 
            ORDER BY ar.time DESC";
    $query = $conexion->query($sql);
    return $query;
}
```

The result is that it shows me the repeated date with their respective records.

What I'm trying to achieve is something like this:

[image]

How could I do it?

PD: The result that I'm getting is this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

But I don't like that...

Comment: Could your show your current result?and provide some data from tables that really help

Comment: the result are really long, cause I have 67 rows in my table with data...but I edit my question, and put some pics of the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The INNER JOIN keyword selects all rows from both tables as long as there is a match between the columns. If there are records in the "Orders" table that do not have matches in "Customers", these orders will not be shown!

The following query should no longer generate duplicate records

```
SELECT 
    ar.id,
    ar.task,
    date_format(ar.date, '%d/%m/%Y') as formattedDate, 
    date_format(ar.time, '%r') as formattedTime, 
    u.user as User 
FROM 
    task_recents ar 
LEFT JOIN 
    user u 
ON 
    u.iduser = ar.iduser 
WHERE 
    date = '$date' 
ORDER BY 
    ar.time 
DESC
```